# Magento CE paypal website payments pro hosted solution

Tags: onepage-checkout, payment-gateway, ce-1.9.1.0, magento-ce, paypal-payments-pro

I have setup a sandbox **Website Payments Pro Hosted Solution** in my website. I'm using one page checkout. 
When I select my payment method to **Payment by cards or by PayPal account** a message shows below the radio button saying **You will be required to enter your payment details after you place an order**. 
But after I place the order shows a PayPal error **This transaction can't be processed. Please pay with another card** and do not show a place to enter payment details such as credit card details.

**Step 1**

[image]

**Step 2**

[image]

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem and found it was caused by website payments pro not being enabled for the sandbox account.